# Mapstruct not selecting overloaded method for optional properties generated by Immutables

Tags: java, mapstruct, immutables-library

I'm using [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io) to generate some classes DTO classes, and Mapstruct to map JPA entities to DTOs. This works great, as long as the DTO has only required properties. If a property is not required (by making the accessor method return an `Optional`, as per the [docs](https://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#optional-attributes)), the builder generated by Immutables will have a setter method with an `Optional` argument, which Mapstruct will fail on:

```
 error: Can't map property "java.lang.Integer id" to "java.util.Optional<java.lang.Integer> id". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.util.Optional<java.lang.Integer> map(java.lang.Integer value)".
```

Makes sense, thankfully there's an [option](https://github.com/immutables/immutables/blob/bef39826f631a62550b0e0f6c504c4fd90b62995/value-annotations/src/org/immutables/value/Value.java#L895) available to also generate methods that take nullable arguments instead. This option generates an *additional* method that takes a nullable argument. However, Mapstruct seems to fail regardless of the presence of this method.

As a workaround, I implemented this abomination (but at this point I'd rather implement the mapping methods myself):

```
@Mapper
public class OptionalMapper {

    public <T> T unwrapOptional(final Optional<T> optional) {
        return optional.orElse(null);
    }

    public <T> Optional<T> wrapIntoOptional(final T value) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(value);
    }
```

Is there any way to make Mapstruct look for overloaded methods (or see the "correct" one first)? Am I going about this the wrong way or simply missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently writing that custom `OptionalMapper` is the way to perform the unwrapping of the optionals.

I don't think that doing that is a bad thing. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/674) for supporting `Optional`

Comment: Hi Filip, thanks for your reply. My issue isn't so much that Mapstruct doesn't unwrap `Optional`s by itself, but more that it doesn't use the overloaded method that takes a nullable argument (which would negate the need for Mapstruct unwrapping `Optional`s). Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've misunderstood the question then. I think that you might be hit by [mapstruct/mapstruct/2377](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2377)